# Generate a number within the range of variables

Tags: batch-file

I want to generate a number in batch with this command

```
Set /a num=%random% %%100
```

but I need to generate the range

```
%%100
```

with a variable
so it will end up like so:

```
set /a num=%nrandom% %%%genlimit%
```

But wont that confuse the batch?

```
%%%genlimit%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - it works fine

```
set var=50
Set /a num=%random% %%%var%
```

or

```
Set /a num=%random% %%%1
```

if you want to take it from the command line

Comment: @TriyogaAriaWardhana it works fine like that, but if you're unsure, add an extra space. `set /a num=%random% %% %var%`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
:loop
set var=5
set /a num=%random% %%var
echo %num%
goto :loop
```